# Drools for large volume of data

Tags: java, drools

We have a requirement where we need to process about 5MM messages in a day and based on certain business rules, generate a unique identifier for messages received asynchronously.

Use case:-

System received message A, message B, message C and message D (standard xml format for all message types).

Business Rule :- If message A contains tag `<tag1>` and value of tag matches against value of either of `<tag2>` , `<tag3>`, `<tag4>` of message B, C or D; assign an identifier assigned for first match. If none matches, generate new identifer and assign to message A. 
Similiar rules applies for message B, C or D.

We thought of using Drools Engine implementation to support above use case but not sure if it will work of such huge amount of data and processed near real time.

Has anyone used Drools Engine to process large amount of data and if so, can you please share the issues or statistical data around the same.

Comment: Do you need to keep all the A, B, C and D messages in your session? Or do these messages arrive in some kind of batch operation and are no longer required after they are tagged?

Comment: How big is each message?

Comment: It is up to you to provide the relevant data. How big is one of A, B, C, or D? What is the "life cycle" of each message after it has been assigned an identifier? What if there is no match?

Answer (score 0):

For simple rules that just check 4 conditions your describe Drools will perform more than fast enough. Just make sure you compile rools just once and not every rule execution. You should likely see performance in order of about few 100_000 of rule invocations per minute in hot state against simple rules like you describe above.

Take a look at these benchmarks for to get better idea:
https://github.com/winklerm/phreak-examples/tree/master/benchmark